# Show action buttons outside aggrid on cell hover

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ReatJS AGGrid enterprise 31.0.3 with Redux.

Requirement:

On cell hover, add/delete button should appear to left side of the cell, outside the grid (designed attached).

Tried 3 approaches:

1. Created a custom cell renderer component with buttons hidden, with position absolute (default state). Custom cell on hover, button appears but inside the cell.
2. Tried with tooltip to position relative to cell. Tooltip clipped. Tried setting z-index, but still clipped.
3. Tried parentPopup with grid onCellMouseOut/onCellMouseOver. Not able to position it beside the cell as these event handler continuously fired. Moreover, getting TypeError in console.

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getColId')
at HeaderCellCtrl2.getColId*

[add/delete button on cell hover design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJaj1.png)

Comment: Please include relevant code.